# Index function is giving me duplicate responses

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

```
def capital_indexes():
    val = []
    pos = []
    x = input("Enter a value\n>>")
    for i in x:
        val.append(i)
    for i in val:
        if i.isupper():
            pos.append(val.index(i))
    print(pos)
capital_indexes()
```

In my code above if I am to input say "HHellO" then I get the output `[0, 0, 5]`. What I am aiming for is to get the index of each capital letter, which would be `[0, 1, 5]`.

Comment: For this to work, you need to start the index search from where you left off in the previous iteration, like `idx = val.index(i, idx+1)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948173/19123103) covers such case.

Comment: `index()` returns the index of the FIRST occurrence.  So in your example above it's finding the first H both times.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this with `enumerate` and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
str_in = input("Enter a value\n>>")  # get string from user ('HHellO')
# iterate over the string, adding the index of each uppercase char to the list
indices = [index for index, char in enumerate(str_in) if char.isupper()]
print(indices)
# => [0, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of multiple loops. It is more efficient, easier to read and more pythonic:

```
my_str = "HHellO"
capital_letter_idxs = [i for i, c in enumerate(my_str) if c.isupper()]
print(capital_letter_idxs)
# [0, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of each capital letter, you can use a `for` loop and keep track of the current index.

Update code:

```py
def capital_indexes():
    val = []
    pos = []
    x = input("Enter a value\n>>")
    for i in x:
        val.append(i)
    for i, char in enumerate(val):
        if char.isupper():
            pos.append(i)
    print(pos)
capital_indexes()
#input ==> HHellO
#output ==> [0, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with index, because it gives you the index of the first occurrence. Below the documentation.

> Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found, such that
> sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and
> end are interpreted as in slice notation.

You can do this instead by keeping track of what step of the array you are. Either using a counter

```
step = 0
for i in val:
    if i.isupper():
        pos.append(step)
    step += 1
```

You can also use enumerate and it will give you two values instead of just i

```
for step, i in enumerate(val):
    if i.isupper():
        pos.append(step)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *'... In my code above if I am to input say "HHellO" then I get the output `[0, 0, 5]`. ...'*

The reason this happens is because you're using the *[index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)* method.
This will return the *index* of the first value.

Instead, utilize the *[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)* built-in function.

```py
s = 'HHellO'
a = []
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c.isupper(): a.append(i)
```

Alternately, use a *[list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*.

```py
s = 'HHellO'
a = [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c.isupper()]
```